Can you run the find command to find files on your system, then include these into the docker image when building
I have a git repo, and I want all the python requirements.txt files to be copied into the docker when I build the image, is this possible or should I use a script to combine them together manually.

The requirements file should be at a fixed place in your repository, and you can COPY it from the place it is into the image.  Does it move often?

the repo has multiple requirements files, and more could be added the idea is to make my life easier but not having to know the location of every one

Can you say a little more about the layout?  I'd generally expect dependencies to be listed in a single pyproject.toml file or equivalent, and requirements.txt to come from pip freeze on a virtual environment.  How do you work with this layout without Docker?
